# Removing img elements in any order

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, kendo-ui, kendo-upload

I am using Kendoui uploaded for async uploads on my site.

A little feature I have is that when an image upload completes, a small thumbnail is created and a preview appears on the page:

```
...
success: function(e)
{
    if(e.operation == 'upload')
    {
        $('#previews').append('<img src="'+ROOT+'cakes/'+e.files[0].name+'"/>');
    }
    else if(e.operation == 'remove')
    {
        $('#previews img[src="'+ROOT+'cakes/'+e.files[0].name+'"]').remove();
    }
...
```

As you can see, I am matching against the img src attribute which I feel may be slow and inefficient. Is there a better way to achieve what I am trying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, if your current code is working, then there's really no need to change it unless you actually have a performance problem.  Modern computers/phones are so darn fast these days that you really only ought to spend time on a performance issue when you actually have a performance issue.  Otherwise your time would be better spent improving your app/page in other ways.

That said, looking something up by id is a lot faster than looking up most other ways (and certainly faster than looking up by an attribute like `src`.  You could coin a unique id from the filename like this, assign it to the image when you create it and then use it to find the image to remove it:

```
success: function(e)
{
    var name = "img_" + e.files[0].name.replace(/[.\/ ]/, "_"); 
    if (e.operation == 'upload')
    {
        $('#previews').append('<img id="' + name + '" src="'+ROOT+'cakes/'+e.files[0].name+'"/>');
    }
    else if(e.operation == 'remove')
    {
        $('#' + name).remove();
    }
...
```